# Node token in rules (Events: When an order is first paid in full)

Tags: nodes, rules, entities

In comments there is Product reference-Inline entity form-Single value, so when a product is posted in comments, it can be bought by somebody.

Is it possible to have a node token in Conditions or Actions in rules when in Events 'When an order is first paid in full' is used? For example, it would be nice to have a node token in Conditions-'Entity has field' and in Actions-'Set a data value'.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your question, but maybe you should try something like using a Rules Action like "Fetch entity by property"?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a node token for that action, but you must load one manually using **Fetch entity by id**.

Comment: Hello, I tried several times to get this token but it doesn't work. May I miss anything? Entity by id mustn't be a particular one, it must also be provided by using a token.